# ElasticSearch - how to not store fields that are not defined in the static index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set a static index with user entity in ES using

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic": "false"
        },
        "user": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "age": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I post a document with more fields than in the index it saves them to the ES.
It doesn't update the mapping but it saves the new fields.
Is there a way to remove the fields that are not in the index?
I dont want to store un-indexed fields.

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping you need to use [`_source` filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#include-exclude):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic": "false"
    },
    "user": {
      "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "id","name","age"
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```